# Bluetooth Device not detected in ubuntu 23.04

Tags: bluetooth, connection, 23.04, bluez

I recently updated to ubuntu 23.04 but unfortunately the bluetooth is not working properly. It only shows a few devices as listed. For example I can see and connect with my android phone but I cannot see my JBL headphone, logitech K-380 Keyboard etc. I have tried most of the methods described in various posts but without any luck. Any help will be appreciated? Let me know if I need to add output of some commands with my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After watching a youtube video I tried the following commands,

```
sudo apt install bluetooth bluez bluez-tools rfkill
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

I am not sure why it worked as all of them were already installed in my system.